# Show Intercept Survey based on IP

Tags: sitecore-client, personalization

I have sitecore Form Intercept Survey that I want to show to random users based on User IP if they have spent specific amount of time on Site.
How to handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

You should go with the `Sitecore IP Geolocation services` to make your component personalize i.e a `MVC Form rendering`.

With the `Sitecore IP Geolocation services`, visitors to your website benefit from a more enhanced, personalized experience with the many tools and activities that marketers can also benefit from.

With IP Geolocation you can set up personalization for different geographical regions and view reports pertinent to those locations. For visitors to your website, you can identify their:

- Time zone
- Longitude and latitude
- Country
- Region
- Metro code
- City
- Post code
- Business name
- DNS address
- **IP address**
- ISP name

Refer to this article for more details.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/getting-started-with-sitecore-ip-geolocation-service.html

So you can apply the personalization rule on your rendering i.e `MVC Form` and show it on the basis of the IP address location.

You can also refer to the below article where people have already used it to make the component personalized on the basis of Geo IP.

https://www.valtech.com/en-in/blog/getting-started-with-sitecore-ip-geolocation-personalization/